# run gdb batch command with `` incorrect

Tags: shell, gdb, command, sh

```
>cmd="/usr/bin/gdb -q --batch -ex 'thread apply all bt full' /proc/8969/exe /tmp/core.xxx"
>ret=`$cmd`
Excess command line arguments ignored. (bt ...)
apply: No such file or directory.
/etc/all: No such file or directory.
Undefined command: "".  Try "help".
>echo $ret

>
```

But -ex 'thread apply all bt full' change to -ex 'bt', the result is correct.
I don't know why,and how to fix it.

type `/usr/bin/gdb -q --batch -ex 'thread apply all bt full' /proc/8969/exe /tmp/core.xxx"` in command line and execute success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
cmd="/usr/bin/gdb -q --batch -ex 'thread apply all bt full' /proc/8969/exe /tmp/core.xxx
ret=`$cmd`
```

After parameter expansion of `$cmd`, the shell will do [field splitting](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05), which splits using the delimiters in $IFS (typically white space). This results in the following fields:

- /usr/bin/gdb
- -q
- --batch
- -ex
- 'thread
- apply
- all
- bt
- full'
- /proc/8969/exe
- /tmp/core.xxx

This tells GDB to execute a command named `'thread`, and to debug an executable named `apply` and core file `all`.

One way to get the results you want is to run

```bash
ret=`eval "$cmd"`
echo "$ret" # use quotes here to preserve newlines
```

If you use bash or other modern shells that support arrays, this might be better:

```bash
gdbargs=(-q --batch -ex 'thread apply all bt full' /proc/8969/exe /tmp/core.xxx)
ret=`/usr/bin/gdb "${gdbargs[@]"}`
echo "$ret"
```